# WineHQ Full Screen Software

Tags: wine, .desktop, fullscreen

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.2 (with the extended support option up to 2021) and I still use some native MS-Windows apps through WineHQ 4.0.1.

I wonder if we can control when some of those apps work in full screen or not.

This is because there are some of them which start to work in full screen mode, without any user action.

Can we change this behaviour? How?

At last, when we are working some of those apps... How can we out momentarily of that full screen condition and back to the standard Linux desktop?

Comment: alt+tab should allow you to get back to your desktop from a full screen app.

Comment: And no, the behavior you can control is the same or less than when running natively in Windows. It depends on the software, not the compatible layer (Wine).

Comment: Thank you so much, Jarad and Gabriela!!!